# How Do I Force Excel To Open A Log File As Text?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to load a log file into Excel as it has timestamps in ms and I need to use Excel to convert them to something readable.

However, it also has an xml tag near the top `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` so Excel thinks it is an xml file, tries to open it using XML Tables then fails because it isn't valid xml.

I want to open it as a delimited text file.

However, even with a macro like this it still tries to open it as XML

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fullpath, _
                            StartRow:=1, _
                            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                            Tab:=True, _
                            Semicolon:=False, _
                            Comma:=False, _
                            Space:=False, _
                            Other:=True, _
                            OtherChar:="|"
```

How do I force Excel to ignore the XML tags and open it as a delimited text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Logic**:

1. Read the file
2. Replace `"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"` with `""`
3. Write the data to a temp file. If you are ok with replacing the original file then you can do that as well. Amend the code accordingly.
4. Open the text file in Excel

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String
    Dim FlName As String, tmpFlName As String

    '~~> I am hardcoding the paths. Please change accordingly
    FlName = "C:\Sample.xml"
    tmpFlName = "C:\Sample.txt"

    '~~> Kill tempfile name if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill tmpFlName
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Open the xml file and read the data
    Open FlName For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    '~~> Replace the relevant tag
    MyData = Replace(MyData, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>", "")
    Close #1

    '~~> Write to a temp text file
    Open tmpFlName For Output As #1
    Print #1, MyData
    Close #1

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=tmpFlName, _
                                StartRow:=1, _
                                DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                                Tab:=True, _
                                Semicolon:=False, _
                                Comma:=False, _
                                Space:=False, _
                                Other:=True, _
                                OtherChar:="|"
End Sub
```

**Alternative Way:**

After

```
'~~> Open the xml file and read the data
Open FlName For Binary As #1
MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , MyData
'~~> Replace the relevant tag
MyData = Replace(MyData, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>", "")
Close #1
```

use

```
strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)
```

and then write this array to Excel and use `.TextToColumns`